# MS CRM custom workflow using early bound

Tags: c#

I have created custom workflow using early bound.The problem is that when I run my custom workflow in MS CRM 2013, I am getting unexpected error(that i mentioned below). Can anybody solve this?

Plugin Trace:

```
[early binding: early_binding.CustomWorkflowEarly]
[early binding (1.0.0.0): early_binding.CustomWorkflowEarly]
```

Error Message:

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Unexpected exception
>   from plug-in (Execute): early_binding.CustomWorkflowEarly:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.Execute(IExecutionContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.ProxyCustomActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   executionContext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client' is not used by CRM so it's not present there by default. You can try to merge it with your workflow assembly or put it in GAC at CRM server. In earlier versions of CRM you could also put referenced assemblies to folder 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Server\bin'.

Comment: Hi pen2,Thank you for your answer. But Its not working. I did not get any Error when i used this "Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll" assembly in my "Plugin" code in MS CRM 2013 online. Could you help me why am not getting in "Custom Workflow".

Comment: You didn't mention before that it's CRM Online. There is not much that we can do here. Could you try and recreate your code with CrmSvcUtil without codecustomization option?

Comment: Hi,I used 'CRM Early Bound Generater' for to create Early bound classes.Is there any other technique to create the class file? If there, Can you please tell me step by step procedure?

Comment: Here is description of CrmSvcUtil http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx